# Writers with a philosophy similar to Eisenbud's

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

When I self study, I have a hard time stopping and solving exercises; I find attempting to prove the theorems in the exposition much more satisfying. My irrational repulsion to exercises/problems stems from the same experience Shimura describes below.

> I discovered that many of the exam problems were artificial and required some clever tricks. I avoided such types, and chose more straightforward problems, which one could solve with standard techniques and basic knowledge.

-Goro Shimura, *The map of my life*, p.115.

But I fear that I might be missing out. After skimming through similar questions on math.SE, I realized that the exercises actually drill the students so as to have them learn common techniques or even topics uncovered in the exposition. That's why I would like to reasonably check my understanding and benefit from exercises in the ways I just described.

When I am lucky, the most difficult ones, i.e., *artificial ones packed with clever tricks,* are marked by an asterisk, etc. When this happens,  I attempt only the unmarked ones before moving on. But this is not always the case, that a writer marks the difficult ones. On the other hand, there are writers like Eisenbud with a radical attitude in this matter.

> The exercises contain a large number of theoretical results, worked out
>   as sequences of problems. **I personally don't like hard exercises very much**; why spend time on them rather than on doing research?

-David Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra with a view towards Algebraic Geometry,* p.6

Now, my request is this:

> Can you suggest me writers that have a philosophy similar to Einsenbud's, preferably writing on algebra, number theory or topology?

Comment: Why do you seem to think _research_ is that different than _hard problems_? For example, _Cantor's Theorem_ (on the cardinality of the power set) could be proposed as a hard problem after some course of say "Numbers and sets" (I had a course with this exact name). It could seem to you as artifcial but it is real math.